# Negating column values and adding particular values in only some columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Taking a Pandas dataframe df I would like to be able to both take away the value in the particular column for all rows/entries and also add another value. This value to be added is a fixed additive for each of the columns.

I believe I could reproduce df, say dfcopy=df, set all cell values in dfcopy to the particular numbers and then subtract df from dfcopy but am hoping for a simpler way.

I am thinking that I need to somehow modify

```
df.iloc[:, [0,3,4]]
```

So for example of how this should look:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 7.0
1   2.0 1.0 8.0 5.0 3.0
2   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 6.0
```

Then negating only those values in columns (0,3,4) and then adding 10 (for example) we would have:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   9.0 3.0 1.0 8.0 3.0
1   8.0 1.0 8.0 5.0 7.0
2   9.0 1.0 1.0 9.0 4.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you create a example dataset and expected dataset so we can copy the data and reproduce the question

Comment: Good idea. I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas is very intuitive in letting you perform these operations,

negate:

```
df.iloc[:, [0,2,7,10,11] = -df.iloc[:, [0,2,7,10,11]
```

add a constant c:

```
df.iloc[:, [0,2,7,10,11] = df.iloc[:, [0,2,7,10,11]+c
```

or change to constant value c:

```
df.iloc[:, [0,2,7,10,11] = c
```

and any other arithmetics you can think of

Answer (score 2):

You can first multiply by `-1` with [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and then add `10` with [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) for those columns we select with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, [0,3,4]] = df.iloc[:, [0,3,4]].mul(-1).add(10)
```

---

```
     A    B    C    D    E
0  9.0  3.0  1.0  8.0  3.0
1  8.0  1.0  8.0  5.0  7.0
2  9.0  1.0  1.0  9.0  4.0
```

---

Or as *anky_91* suggested in the comments:

```
df.iloc[:, [0,3,4]] = 10-df.iloc[:,[0,3,4]]
```

---

```
     A    B    C    D    E
0  9.0  3.0  1.0  8.0  3.0
1  8.0  1.0  8.0  5.0  7.0
2  9.0  1.0  1.0  9.0  4.0
```

Comment: I edited the question to take away instead of negate. Definitely confusing. This method is also awesome, definitely helpful in terms of one can chain (?) other arguments.